# I want to scrape reddit data using praw. I am getting raise ResponseException(response) error after adding the for loop

Tags: reddit, praw

```
subredditcmv=reddit.subreddit('changemyview')
cmv_subreddit=subredditcmv.top(limit=15)
cmv_dict={"Title":[], \
          "Score":[], \
          "id":[], \
          "number_of_comments":[],\
          "post":[],\
          "created":[]
          }
for posts in cmv_subreddit:
    cmv_dict["Title"].append(posts.title)
    cmv_dict["Score"].append(posts.score)
    cmv_dict["id"].append(posts.id)
    cmv_dict["number_of_comments"].append(posts.num_comments)
    cmv_dict["post"].append(posts.selftext)
    cmv_dict["created"].append(posts.created)
```

receiving this error

> File "C:\Users\source\repos\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line
>   31, in _post
>       raise ResponseException(response)
>
> ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [401 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) mean that your request lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource. You need to [authenticate yourself](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html#) with the reddit api.
However, if you only want to fetch data, you can use the [read-only mode](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettinag_started/authentication.html#read-only-mode) or request the data to the [reddit api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#section_subreddits) yourself

Answer (score 1):

You are not authenticated with reddit's API ([see the PRAW authentication page](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html#)). Logging in first should fix this issue.